# take only the first element of a functions output python

Tags: python

given a function, like split(" ",1) whats the most pythonic way to take the first element of its output only, for example given:

```
x= "a sequence of words"
x.split(" ",1)
```

I would like to get the string "a"

Comment: `x.split(" ",1)[0]`

Comment: `first, *_ = x.split(" ", 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the split a list is returned, so use indexing to get the first element:

```
x= "a sequence of words"
print(x.split(" ",1)[0])
```

Comment: I omitted the quotes inside the parentheses since split on space is the default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean? where 0 is the index

```
x = "a sequence of words"
print(x[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's use the variable x you stated, and input the first character from x into another variable y:

```
x = "a sequence of words"
y = x[0]
```

If you print y, you'll get the output 'a'. This is because the characters in a string can be indexed just like the items in a list. 0 is the first index, 1 is the second, and so on and so forth. You could also use the knowledge of indexing to print out a range of characters(For example, `'a sequence'`).

```
z = x[0:10]
```

It's important to note that you have to count the spaces, and that this is upper-bound exclusive(i.e It won't print the last number), so add one to the character index where you want to stop.

Answer (score 0):

The most "pythonic" method is an opinion. However any method like split which returns a list you can simply index the list at 0 to get the first item.

`a = x.split(" ", 1)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the first index

Example:

```py
x.split(" ",1)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn’t this work as well?

```
x.split()[0]
```